# Reseting a store object to a default value in SolidJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy, solid-js

How would you completely reset a value in a store in **SolidJS**

I have something akin to:

```
interface Item { id: number, price: number, quantity: number } 
​interface State { items: Array<Item> }

export const ItemsContext = createContext()

export const ContextProvider = (props: any) => { 
     const [state, setState] = createStore({items: []})
     
     const incrementItemQuantity = ({id}: Item) => {
         const index = state.items.findIndex(i => i.id === id)

         if(index !== -1) {
             const item = state.items[index] 
             setState("items", index, {quantity: item.quantity + 1})
         }
     }

     const clearItems  = () => {
       setState(produce(s => s.items = []))
     }

     const addItem = (item: Item) => {
       setState(produce(s => s.items.push(item))
     }
    
    const value = [state, { addItem, clearItems, incrementItemQuantity} ]
    return (
     <ItemsContext.Provider value={value} >
      { props.children }
     <ItemsContext.Provider/>
    )
    
}
```

Adding an item and incrementing its quantity works as expected.
When I:

1. Add an item.
2. Increment its quantity
3. Clear the items

I expect the state to be blank. However, If I add an item with the same properties as the first to the list, it is displayed with the old values.

I can't figure out why. What am I not doing right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the store API correctly. For example, the item path gives you the item, you should get the item first, than update it through a setter:

```js
setState("items", index, {quantity: item.quantity + 1});
```

Here is how you can do it correctly:

```js
// Here path gives us the item
setState("items", index, item => ({...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1}));

// Here path gives us the property
setState('items', index, 'quantity', q => q + 1);
```

Here is how you can do it. I did not expose store but items. It is up to you.

```js
// @refresh reload
import { createContext, JSX, useContext } from "solid-js";
import { createStore, produce } from 'solid-js/store';
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

interface Item { id: number, price: number, quantity: number }

interface Store {
  items: () => Array<Item>;
  add?: (item: Item) => void;
  increment?: (index: number) => void;
  clear?: () => void;
};

export const CartContext = createContext<Store>();

export const CartProvider = (props: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const [store, setStore] = createStore({ items: [{ id: 0, price: 10, quantity: 1 }] })

  const items = () => store.items;
  const add = (item: Item) => setStore('items', items => [...items, item]);
  const increment = (index: number) => setStore('items', index, 'quantity', q => q + 1);
  const clear = () => setStore('items', []);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ items, add, increment, clear }}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const { items, add, increment, clear } = useContext(CartContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items().map((item, index) => (
          <li>{JSON.stringify(item)} <button onclick={() => increment(index)}>inc</button></li>)
        )}
      </ul>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => add({ id: items().length, price: 10, quantity: 1 })}>Add Item</button>
        {` `}
        <button onClick={() => clear()}>Clear Items</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <Child />
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

render(App, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the store correctly. Check this live example [here](https://playground.solidjs.com/?version=1.4.1#NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGGUCWEwBowBcCeADgsrgM4Ae2YZA9gK4BOAxiWGjIbY7gAQi9GcCABM4jXgF9eAM0a0YvADo1aAGzQiAtACsyAegDucAEYqA3EogcuPfr2ZCouOAGFaEFxVxZe9Mm4eXj68AGLcUrLyiip0Gtp6FlY23HwCjnDOcADKuNxwkXIKyqrxugZkeUJJEFZwFLZ8zB6VvO70nuLund68ALwOTi7dwQAUoLxoLjBkiLzAALpSviCSCwCUlhD1jbIdzLhoHm0MnYwACvIAbprio4TyhLNQEPjr-Fa8Di18wJVZvgCuFyWSWAwyWVy+VGAimcBmcwetCeADo4TNeAAfTHzBaSTafb4QVqVfKIF74frzQlff4uLA0j4QL4s3hQEQiOajK5QNSICD0GAmcTvPoAPl4QJBLlGKnRZBUvlG8tFEuAKI18t8PLUGwZzNZDjUmUYXNVkrgwNwWVl7GmCuwvFG5sW631hsE8NoVzgXPR-MFwsY5ql1plcvtiqdKv6EvlKJkaDULkYo2VAaFIvFk14AEI+gN0es3YzJO7eAstoShLgmMzZQavgAedpnEb1XAoy7e24SHX0OB9ECkoSSMWMr4gJGo5gACyTIiEEEkjKb+lbKfb3i711744NBOXViszWJfA34ipztjTK+p9afzDcBWbI5WGYxqgjF8Qhg3oKaxUv4gQ9LgTYUmKowXowW64IeXw1nWvBNiIaBXJKBDGkOIATiUqCMAA5hgKhzAA5AAjL+pGlmOq4mPQuB5AaHiuBozAANZDte2bsiIox0nAaL2iixoQARuCzrwADUvDkes0iVPgWEgDhjYsio+FERAWiMGgBGzrgJG8BRVE0RKACCHLIfo9GMR4+6sk2tlMV8LFsZxIAfiaY6sSa1nOfZq7hBImRzkOAlCfCZC0Wpk7pgKmbBjeoxNrO5G8G5aAcVx5q-v+yryWKIBoJIa5pWK8mrvowUOSya6oVc+6SFWED3nw5mEIQV7mg2zbQd2NxiIwtV9acKa8PotVrv1u5Dfuh5LkNabmk2HVdZNvgiLQzCCsInYEZaACixrwJ4ABC+AAJJ8SoUCdSo6y5oeYBrEAA)

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createContext, useContext, For } from "solid-js";
import { createStore } from "solid-js/store";

export const CounterContext = createContext([{ items: [] }, {}]);
export function CounterProvider(props) {
  const [state, setState] = createStore({ items: props.items || []});
  const store = [
    state,
    {
      add: (val) => setState("items", (c) => [...c, val]),
      clear: () => setState("items", () => []),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={store}>
      {props.children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}

const Counter = () => {
  const [state, { add,clear }] = useContext(CounterContext);
  return <>
    <For each={state.items}>
      {(i) => (<h1>{i}</h1>)}
    </For>
    <button  onClick={() => add(state.items.length + 1)}>Add </button>
    <button  onClick={clear}>Clear </button>
    </>
};

const App = () => (
  <CounterProvider>
    <Counter />
  </CounterProvider>
);
render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```